# Bash-shell Replace separator between specific column

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
input file:
cat file1.txt
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb bitRatePerQci=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb bufferStatus=1
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb noOfArtificialUsers=0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb qciDistSinrHigh=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb qciDistSinrLow=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb qciDistSinrMedium=100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$ trafficModelPrb ulDlRatioPerQci=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

output file:
cat file2.txt
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;bitRatePerQci=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;bufferStatus=1
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;noOfArtificialUsers=0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;qciDistSinrHigh=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;qciDistSinrLow=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;qciDistSinrMedium=100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^AirIfLoadProfile=1$;trafficModelPrb;ulDlRatioPerQci=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Replace the space separator in column 1 between column 2 , and column 2 between column 3 with semicolon. The file2 is the output .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see shell, awk and sed code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed 's/ /;/1;s/ /;/1'   Input_file
```

Where I am substituting the very first space in a line with `;`(semi colon) and then again changing the very first space with `;`(semi colon) because after first change of space in a line the 2nd space becomes 1st space now so we need to put 1st space only by doing `/1` in `sed` command.